# How PREF cookie (google.com) appears in firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

Remove all the history in Firefox (delete all cookies), disable all add-ons and plugins, then restart Firefox. *Do not go to any site* and wait for about 10-15 min. Go to *Options->...->Show cookies*. You will see cookie named **PREF** with *google.com* domain.
1) Can somebody explain how and why this cookie appears?
2) How to get rid of this?

p.s I don't have any google desktop application installed. Firefox google search bar is removed too.

Comment: your startup page is set to `about:blank`?

Comment: The answer which you have accepted is not working for me. Did it ever work for you at all?

Comment: Turning off both safe-browsing checkboxes AND disabling ALL cookies still creates the Google.com PREF cookie for me! I even removed the Google URLs from `about:config`!

Comment: i found the .mozilla/<..profile_dir..>/cookies.sqlite -sqlite3-db-file where cookies are stored, removing the PREF-cookie there has no effect for me (!!)

Comment: the accepted solution works _in combination_ with its comment. The comment about deletion of the initially-installed cookie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This cookie is coming from Google's safebrowsing api:

```
google.com/safebrowsing/downloads?client=....
```

This is a known issue in firefox and there is an open ticket here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=368255

*EDIT* To get rid of it, you can turn off the safebrowsing on the security tab (under Options), by un-checking the boxes to Block attacks and forgeries.

Comment: As of today the answer is wrong. Google themselves officially [state](https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/) that the `PREF` cookie is used to store the information that you do not use Google's safebrowsing: *The PREF cookie may store your preferences and other information, in particular your preferred language (e.g. English), how many search results you wish to have shown per page (e.g. 10 or 20), and whether or not you wish to have Google’s SafeSearch filter turned on*

Comment: @gentmatt disagree with you. I have this cookie on localhost, and only turn off block attacks and forgeries options, allowed me to delete it.

Comment: Turning off both safe-browsing checkboxes AND disabling ALL cookies still creates the Google.com PREF cookie for me! I even removed the Google URLs from `about:config`!

Comment: For those who already have the ``google.com`` PREF cookie it may prove difficult to remove since you cannot delete the cookie from the cookie manager. You have to manually delete the cookie from the sqlite store. The relevant bug is [#1026538](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1026538).
After opening the cookies database with ``sqlite3 cookies.sqlite3``, you can delete the cookies with: ``DELETE FROM moz_cookies WHERE baseDomain = "google.com";``

Comment: @ariddell very useful comment, thanks! I also want to add that deleting ALL the cookies will do the job, too (deleting the file `cookies.sqlite`). Note also that it's dangerous, you really will have all your cookies deleted.

Comment: This was not sufficient for me, I'd suggest KrisWebDev's answer instead.

Answer (score 10):

### Why does it appear?

> As part of [Safe Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work), Web browsers ping Google periodically for
>   updated lists of potentially dangerous sites. When they do, Google
>   puts a cookie on the user’s machine. Google says the cookie helps it
>   keep its system stable and monitor for attacks.

*Source: [The Google Cookie That Seems to Come Out of Nowhere](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2012/02/28/the-google-cookie-that-seems-to-come-out-of-nowhere/)*

### Why does it keep reappearing even after I delete it?

1. Because you need to disable Safe Browsing
2. **AND** because Firefox Cookie Manager can't delete it, even if it appears to (bug [#1026538](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1026538)).

### Why is it dangerous?

As this cookie contains a unique ID number, it has been used by the NSA to track people under suspicion. *Source: [NSA uses Google cookies to pinpoint targets for hacking](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2013/12/10/nsa-uses-google-cookies-to-pinpoint-targets-for-hacking), Washington Post*

Also, it means Google can track you better since this unique ID is persistent even after you close Firefox.

Security often means less privacy. You can avoid sending all your browsing history to Google: Use an up-to-date browser and modules, disable uneeded browser modules, don't install apps/modules from untrusted sources and avoid phishing attempts by checking the website domain and HTTPS certificate.

### How to really get rid of it?

1. Disable Safe Browsing:

   1.1 Uncheck "Block reported attack sites" under Firefox Preferences > Security tab

   1.2. Uncheck "Block reported web forgeries" under Firefox Preferences > Security tab
2. **THEN** manually delete the existing cookie with sqlite3 (as long as bug [#1026538](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1026538) is open)

   2.1. Find your Firefox cookie database within your Firefox profile folder:

   Firefox menu > Help button > `Troubleshooting Information` > `Application Basics` section > `Profile folder` line > `Open Directory` button > File name is **`cookies.sqlite`**

   or *(Ubuntu)* `find ~/.mozilla/firefox -name cookies.sqlite`

   2.2 Install sqlite3: [Download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) or (Linux) `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

   2.3 From command prompt: `sqlite3`*`path-to-cookies.sqlite`*

   2.4 `DELETE FROM moz_cookies WHERE baseDomain = "google.com";`

Now you can check that the PREF cookie doesn't reappear at Firefox launch in Firefox Cookie Manager. It should not reappear as long as you don't re-enable Safe Browsing and if you have configured Firefox to delete cookies after exit.

Recommeded tools to limit tracking (except PREF cookie...): [Cookie AutoDelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/)

Comment: After Disabling Safe Browsing, it's easier to just delete the PREF cookie from the FF options, it's the same as going through the sqlite3 exercise posted in step 2.

Comment: Cookie Manager can't delete this cookie, even if it appears to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301114/how-pref-cookie-google-com-appears-in-firefox/28262564#comment39505714_6301223

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what ended up working for me, although I accomplished it in a simpler more brute force way: (1) toggle 'browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled' and 'browser.safebrowsing.phishing.enabled', (2) delete cookies.sqlite* in profile dir [http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox]. This is probably the dumbest thing I've ever seen--a tracking cookie for helping to stop tracking ...or the smartest thing from the most nefarious of people. <shrug> Open source software FTW.

Answer (score 5):

It's used by the NSA and GCHQ to spy on people!

http://rt.com/usa/nsa-advertisers-cookies-track-browsers-034/

Answer (score 3):

Google has updated their policies page to explain what types of cookies they use, specifically the `PREF` cookie.

But beforehand I will say that I [can't explain](https://superuser.com/questions/723331/this-google-cookie-is-indestructable) where and how this cookie pops up in the browser. It seems to be done by firefox itself even if you don't use Google search, Google safebrowsing and block cookies for °.google.com

Google's policies page states that:

> #### Preferences
>
> ...
>   The PREF cookie **may** store your preferences and other information, in particular your preferred language (e.g. English), how many search results you wish to have shown per page (e.g. 10 or 20), and **whether or not you wish to have Google’s SafeSearch filter turned on**.
>
> #### Advertising
>
> ... Google uses cookies, like the PREF cookie, to help **personalize ads** on Google properties, like Google Search, particularly when you aren’t signed in to a Google account. ...

Maybe it's part of the undisclosed contract between Mozilla and Google to set this unblockable zombie cookie. Who knows? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Click Show Cookies - Don't just delete the Google cookie but click 'Remove All Cookies'  Remove the check mark from the 'Accept cookies from sites' box

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to disable the google pref cookie in previous firefox-versions but since version 28 it is NOT possible to disable the google pref cookie! Mozilla integrated this cookie because google wants it - and google is paying millions of dollars for mozilla to keep this spying cookie in the firefox-browser enabled. Iam using now the comodo icedragon-browser, its based on firefox 26, you can install addons and themes from mozilla too, and most important you can disable the google-pref cookie: Go to options - privacy - enable custom settings - uncheck accepting cookies and remove the stored cookies if you have any (also add the links in which you login to the exception list). This cookie will never appear again. I hope Comodo dont update this browser to the newer ff-base.

Answer (score 0):

I effectively deleted the google.com pref cookie.  Do this:

about:config
safe

delete all values that reference google.com

It works and I've experienced no degradation in performance.

Answer (score 0):

This, er, feature has undergone several rebrandings -- from "safe browsing" to "phishing protection" and now (FF 49) to "block dangerous and deceptive content".  No doubt it will soon become "Protect tiny kittens".

Answer (score -4):

Another way in Firefox is to click Exceptions under Options/Privacy/"use custom settings for history"; type in "google.com" and click Block. That way google.com will not be stored on your computer from then on. (If you have a gmail address, you can't access it unless you store google's cookie).